# cloud9-ide: how to delete workspace?

Tags: cloud9-ide

Is there ability to delete the workspace from cloud9 ? 
and also don't see (in IDE) to commit the changes into git (bitbucket) , because of project was initially imported from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check out Cloud9 Documentation about [workspace deletion](https://docs.c9.io/docs/deleting-a-workspace).

Regarding git, you can use the Cloud9 workspace's Terminal to run any git command. We also have an experimental Git UI in the works. Please note that it is still in beta. You can enable it by going to Preferences (Cloud9 > Preferences). Click on 'Experimental' and then enable 'Changes Panel'.

Once enabled, you might have to refresh the page once. Then look at the far right of the IDE where the tabs for 'Workspace', 'Navigate' etc are. The last one should be 'Changes'. Click on that to view the changes panel. You can use that to view diffs on your files, make commits, push and pull to and from your remote repo.